# Is this a short cage or long cage rear derailleur?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear

[image]

Is there an easy, objective way to tell?

Comment: IMO this question is too specific and should be better phrased as "how do I tell the difference between short/med/long rear derailleurs". Otherwise we're opening ourselves up to a string of extremely specific questions like this one and yesterdays ["is this long"](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/24052/7044) one.

Answer (score 1):

The objective way to tell is by calculating the total capacity and matching that to the make and model of the derailleur.

[This has an excellent answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7264/how-to-calculate-the-capacity-of-a-rear-derailleur) for calculating derailleur capacity.