# Is there any reason I can't convert a 36/46 to a 36/52 chainring?

Tags: crankset

My commuter bike is a converted cross bike (really just a cross bike with a rack on it).  It works great, but I occasionally wish I had a higher top end gear.  The crankset that came on it is a 36/46 cross gearing.  Is there any reason I can't just swap out the 46t chainring with a 52t?  It's all Ultegra 6800 stuff, and the cassette is an 11-32 cassette. I guess my biggest concern is that the chain might not be long enough if I ever cross-chain the 52t chainring and the 32t cog.

Comment: I have a CX with Ultgra 6600 and have run both 48 and 53.  You will most likely need to move derailleur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is: since 50/34 and 11/32 works well, because it is commonly used, so should 52/36 and 11/32. Same tooth difference (16) between the front chainrings. Same total capacity (read further).

Take a look at [this technical document](http://si.shimano.com/php/download.php?file=pdf/ev/EV-FC-6800-3609A.pdf)
For Item 11 (inner chainring), it says `Chainring 36T-MB for 46-36T/52-36T`
For Item 12 (outer chainring), it says `Chainring 52T-MB for 52-36T`
I think you can conclude from that: 52-36 is supported by Shimano.

Now for the rear derailleur:
Ultegra RD-6800 comes in two cage lengths: short (RD-6800 SS) and long (RD-6800 GS)
Use [this post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7264/how-to-calculate-the-capacity-of-a-rear-derailleur) as a guide to choose between the two.
Your total capacity becomes `32 - 11 + 52 - 36 = 37`.
That's the maximum for the long cage.

Now about the chain:
[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnRxNHkRh8Q&t=29) illustrates perfectly how to determine the correct chain length. It shows that you need to use the inner chain ring and the smallest cog on the cassette (36-11). If you follow this rule, your chain length should be OK. Indeed the rear derailleur will be stretched even further than it already was in the other extreme (52-32).

Also an interesting read: [Sheldon Brown's take on derailleurs](http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/derailers-rear.html)

Comment: That first link is not working. Linked to a file on your computer.

Comment: Sounds good.  Thanks.  Now I just need to buy myself a 52t chain ring.