# Can the SRAM Rival 1 rear derailleur be used with an 11-46T cassette?

Tags: cassette, derailleur-rear, sram

I want to put the **SRAM Rival 1** group on my next bike. Somewhere I heard that the rear derailleur can handle **11-46T** cassettes despite the [official documentation](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/rd-riv-1-a2).

Is that true?

Are there any limitations for the chainring?

Comment: If it 'works', 'Works is likely to be  Apex or worse shifting at RIval prices.

Comment: Apex and rival shift identically. You aren't paying for better shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bikepacking.com has an article about "mullet" drivetrains](https://bikepacking.com/gear/guide-to-mullet-drivetrains/#I). One of the drivetrains consists of a Rival 1 rear derailleur with a 9-46T cassette. They write:

> The SRAM Rival 1 derailleur works flawlessly, and even though SRAM specifies the max capacity at 42-tooth cassette cogs, it has no issues with a 46.

They even have a [drivetrain with a 10-50T cassette but with a replaced derailleur cage](https://bikepacking.com/gear/guide-to-mullet-drivetrains/#II).

Answer (score 2):

Having fitted a few of these, it works on some bikes better than others. I think this is to do with derailleur bolt drop distance. The derailleur can struggle shifting in and out of the 46.

I have had more success using these derailleurs on 11-46t 10sp cassettes with 10sp shifters where the margin for error is better.

The size of the front ring doesn't matter as long as the chain is the right length.

Answer (score 1):

With a 1x system, any practically sized chainring will work.  Do you already own this derailleur?

I expect that you can probably get this to work with a 46T cassette, but my suggestion would be not to buy a new one with that intention.

Hacking bike parts is great fun, my hobby.  But when you are buying something new you should buy it for its intended purpose.  I expect you will be able to find a similar derailleur that is comparably priced that is rated for the 46T cog.

If you already own it, that is a different story.  You might try to find a friend with a 11-46 cassette that you can tryout before buying one.  They are pretty common.  If you already have both parts, sure give it a try and let us know.

By coincidence, I just answered a similar question [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/73182/11t-40t-42t-cassette-on-3x9-system).  I describe two success stories with derailleurs working on cassettes that are a little bigger than they are supposed to be.

Comment: I haven't bought the parts yet. I'll take a look if I find a derailleur that works with the break-shifting-levers.

Answer (score 1):

It even works with 11-51!! Just need b screw adjustment. Apex 1 and rival 1 type 3.0

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE! This is a great start to an answer! Could you please add a bit more detail? Do you know this from experience? Or did you read it somewhere? Also, how much adjustment on the b screw? Tightened or loosened? If you really wanted to go the extra mile, you could ad a picture of where to find the b screw.