# Chainring compatible

Tags: chainring, compatibility, drivetrain

i have a Alivio m3100 Cassette cs Hg400 (12-36T) and m3100 rd, can i installed a 2x crankset Gxp (28-38T) on my drivetrain alivio???[image]

Answer (score 2):

Specifically to your question, your bicycle's bottom bracket will define the crankset type (GPX, BB30, BSA...) - not your groupset.

However, when upgrading cranksets you need to also consider a number of other factors like derailleur capacity.

The Alivio groupset supports 3x and 2x cranksets, according to the Shimano product page: https://bike.shimano.com/en-AU/product/component/alivio-m3100.html

The rear derailleur Alivio RD-M3100-SGS has a total capacity of 45T so keep that in mind when selecting the chainring sizes (More details [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7264/how-to-calculate-the-capacity-of-a-rear-derailleur))